# Why won't this code work to create a Parse object in an Ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a Parse object in an app using the Ionic Framework, and I can't get it to work. I'm fairly new to programming, but I've been able to create Parse users, just not objects. Can anyone help me find a solution? Please see the code below for my controller in question. Thanks!

.controller('AddProspectsController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope) {

```
if (!$rootScope.isLoggedIn) {
    $state.go('welcome');
}

$scope.prospect = {};
$scope.error = {};

// Syntax to create a new subclass of Parse.Object.
//var Prospects = Parse.Object.extend("Prospects");

$scope.addProspect = function() {

    // Create a new instance of that class.
    var Prospects = Parse.Objext.extend("Prospects");
    var prospects = new Prospects();
    prospect.set("name", $scope.prospect.name);
    prospect.set("phone", $scope.prospect.phone);
    prospect.set("email", $scope.prospect.email);
    prospect.set("interest", $scope.prospet.interest);

    prospect.save(null, {
      success: function(prospect) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        $state.go('app.prospects', {clear: true});
        alert('New object created with objectId: ' + prospect.id);
      },
      error: function(prospect, error) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.prospect);
      }
    });
}
```

})

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have another spelling error on this line:

```
 var Prospects = Parse.Objext.extend("Prospects");
```

This is not `Objext`, but `Object`.​​​​​​

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling error... you have the variable named `prospects` with an ***"s"*** and when you are creating the object, you are using a variable named `prospect`

Comment: I made the correction but it's still not working. I'm getting an error in the console though that says 

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined" 

in reference to this line:

var Prospects = Parse.Objext.extend("Prospects");